# Цикл While. Сумма чисел

Tags: python

Нужно считывать целые числа до тех пор, пока не встретится фраза: "The End". Вывести сумму считанных чисел.

```
summ = 0
s = input()
while s != "The End":
    summ +=  int(s)
    s = input(s)
print (summ)
```

ВВОД:

```
3
5
The End
```

Выводит `358`, хотя должен выводить`8`.

Comment: Прикольный кейс ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> s = input(s)
> ```

```
s = input()
```

Полностью: https://ideone.com/O2FMHe

Answer (score 2):

То, что в скобках `input()`, то выводится на печать. Поэтому уже введенные значения (3 и 5) печатаются, а потом и сумма (8). Вот и получается 358.

```
s = input() # убрать s из скобок
```